# Exporting file from Blender 3.0.0 to use in Blender 2.92.0

Tags: blend-files, versions

I've been working on a scene with the newer **3.0.0** version, but a custom plugin I need to use only works with **2.92.0**. I still have the old version installed, so tried to open the .blend file with it and got an error stating that the file is incompatible.

Is there a way I can export the entire .blend file for compatibility with older versions? Or should I just try and export all the content out and reimport in a new scene? I'd definitely prefer the first option if there is a way to do it, otherwise I should be able to find a workaround.

Comment: If you're saving the 3.0 version as a compressed file, 2.92 can't read it all.  Try saving it as an uncompressed file. 2.92 might be able to read it but you'll still have to check it out to see whether you've used 3.0 features that you need to work around.

Comment: Ahh that was it! Unchecking 'Compressed' when saving did the trick, thanks for saving me a bunch of time!

Comment: Glad that worked for you.  You're very welcome.